# looping rename command for duplicates cmd/batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am creating a script as a .cmd and have a command that renames a folder from "test" to "test.old" on some occasions there may already be a "test.old" that exists creating a duplicate error so I implemented a very redimentry workaround but am trying to figure out how to loop this command so it adds a variable number if a duplicate exists.

E.g If test1.old it renames to test2.old and if that exists then it renames to test3.old etc..

```
REN "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\test" "test.old"

if %errorlevel% == 0 goto :TESTNOERRORS if %errorlevel% == 1 goto :TESTDUP


:TESTDUP

REN "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\test" "test1.old"


REN "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\test" "test2.old"


:TESTNOERRORS
```

What would the most efficient way to do this in a .cmd script?

P.s I am very new to scripting in general as well as programming,

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it :

```
REN "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\test" "test.old"
if %errorlevel% == 1 goto :TESTDUP
goto :END
:TESTDUP
REN "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\test" "test%it%.old"
if %errorlevel% == 0 goto :END
set /A it+=1
goto :TESTDUP
:END
```

If the first REN not work the loop try to rename the folder until it find an available name

Comment: That works perfectly! Although is there a way to kill the loop if it runs for too long if maybe no file is found for example? I'm thinking I could add a timeout to the process?

Comment: You can stop the loop for a particular value of "it" using if :
`if %it%==500 goto :end`

Comment: The command line `set /A it=1` is never going to be executed. And you could simplify `set /A it=%it%+1` to `set /A it+=1`...

Answer (score 0):

Retrying the rename operation based on `errorlevel` is not a good idea because the rename can also be failed for variety of reasons other than duplicate name conflicts. for example when the source does not exist or when you have not sufficient permissions to rename the object or when the target is in use,...

A more general approach would be something like this

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "FSObjToRename=PathToFileOrFolder"
set /a "start#=1, maxRetries=10000, end#=start#+maxRetries"
set "q=""
for %%F in ("%FSObjToRename%") do (
    set "SpawnCommand=for /L %%# in (%start#%,1,%end#%) do @if not exist %%q%%%FSObjToRename%.%%#.old%%q%% (ren %%q%%%FSObjToRename%%%q%% %%q%%%%~nxF.%%#.old%%q%% & exit)"

    REM This is a more readable form of the SpawnCommand:
    REM for /L %%# in (%start#%,1,%end#%) do @if not exist "%FSObjToRename%.%%#.old" (ren "%FSObjToRename%" "%%~nxF.%%#.old" & exit)
)

if exist "%FSObjToRename%" cmd /e:on /v:off /d /s /c "%SpawnCommand%"
```

The above code avoids `:Labels` and `GOTOs` completely by executing the rename loop in new instance of `CMD.EXE` so it can break the loop by `exit` command but if the string for `SpawnCommand` looks weird and confusing (mainly because of `%%q%%` to hide quotation marks from batch file parser) then **for small number of retries**, the loop can be rewritten like this

```
if exist "%FSObjToRename%" for %%F in ("%FSObjToRename%") do (
    for /L %%# in (%start#%,1,%end#%) do (
        if not exist "%FSObjToRename%.%%#.old" (ren "%FSObjToRename%" "%%~nxF.%%#.old" & goto :break)
    )
)
:break
```

Using `goto` inside of `FOR loop` will prevent the execution of the `loop body` but does not break to `loop iterator` (It will blindly count to `%end#%`) so there would be a delay between executing `goto :break` and actually going to `:break`, by the amount which depends on the number of iterations

What is considered `small` for number of retries, completely depends on the performance of the computer. For today computers you may not notice a delay even for `100000` iterations. for small enough retries the latter will have slightly better performance than to launching new instance of `cmd` but the former is more robust in handling arbitrary retries.

Using backward `GOTOs` (when target Label is above the `GOTO` command) should be avoided whenever possible specially when the number of iterations have the potential be large and size of the batch script is not small.